# Keep Header Fix in Responsive Scrollable Table

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an Application in Angular 2 having Table with Thousand's of Record.When I scroll Down,I want my Header to be fixed.How can I achieve the same?

I have tried setting Head to be fixed and setting Max-width of Column,but both of them didn't Worked.
P.S -Since it is an Angular Application,I want to Avoid JQuery as much as Possible.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `position: fixed;` for you header. and you can also use bootstrap Affix plugin for the same.

Answer (score -1):

here is your table format

```
<table>
<thead>
   <th>fname</th>
   <th>lname</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>john</td><td>doe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>john</td><td>doe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>john</td><td>doe</td>
</tr>

</tbody> 
</table>
```

this is css for that table

```
table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block;
    border:1px solid red;
}

table tbody 
{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
}

th , td
{
    width: 50px;
}
```

here https://jsfiddle.net/mf6hg9jq/2/

Comment: On Display block,my whole tbody gets shrinked and also It doesn't seem to be responsive.

Comment: here you can use angular wise --> https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/angularjs-fixed-header-scrollable-table-directive